# passing an object having array to oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I've a class "User" as follows:

```
public class User{
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String[] departments;


}
```

I want to pass an object of User type to my oracle stored procedure that takes an object type as parameter. So I did this to achieve my solution:-

```
1. Created USER_SEARCH_OBJ as a type in database as follows:-
      create or replace
        TYPE USER_SEARCH_OBJ AS OBJECT (
              FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(256),
              LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(256), 
              DEPARTMENTS TABLE_OF_VALUES,
        );

2. Created TABLE_OF_VALUES as a type in database as follows:-
      create or replace TYPE TABLE_OF_VALUES AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);

3. Passed the User object from Java class as follows:-
       Object[] departments = {"1","2"};
       StructDescriptor objDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("USER_SEARCH_OBJ", conn.getMetaData().getConnection());
       ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("TABLE_OF_VALUES", conn.getMetaData().getConnection());
       ARRAY departmentArr = new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, conn.getMetaData().getConnection(), departments );
       Object[] userProperties = new Object[2];
       userProperties [0] = "paras";//first_name
       userProperties [1] = "anand";//last_name
       userProperties [2] = departmentArr ;//department array
       STRUCT searchObj = new STRUCT(objDescriptor, conn.getMetaData().getConnection(), userProperties );
       CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("PCK_SEARCH2.USER_SEARCH(?,?)");
       cStmt.setObject(1, searchObj);
       cStmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
       cStmt.execute();
```

But when I run this code I get an exception as follows:-

```
java.sql.SQLException: Inconsistent java and sql object types
    at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.toOracleArray(StructDescriptor.java:709)
    at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.toArray(StructDescriptor.java:1296)
    at oracle.sql.STRUCT.<init>(STRUCT.java:165)
    at com.ensenda.lmp.web.controller.User.main(User.java:75)
```

This exception comes at the following line of code:-

```
STRUCT searchObj = new STRUCT(objDescriptor, conn.getMetaData().getConnection(), userProperties );
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Java and Oracle types are not equivalent.  You'll either need to pass the elements of your Java class as individual parameters to your procedure, or write your stored proc in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think you should get an **ArrayOutOfBoundException** because you have declared an Object[2] and trying to put a 3rd element into it. Considering that is a typo.

For the original problem instead of using setObject you can use 
 *JDBCUtil.setStruct(conn,cStmt,1,"USER_SEARCH_OBJ",userProperties);*